# Warning message when trying to predict labels for more test data than training data

Tags: r, predict

When I run this code (or any similar code for that matter):

```
x1 <- c(runif(100, 0.0, 10.0))
y1 <- c(runif(100, 0.0, 10.0))

data <- data.frame(x1, y1)
data$label <- with(data, ifelse((x1-5)^2 + (y1-5)^2 < 9, 1, 0))

lm_fit <- lm(formula = label ~ .,data = data)

x_vals <- seq(0, 10, 0.25)
y_vals <- seq(0, 10, 0.25)

grid <- expand.grid(x_vals, y_vals)

predict(lm_fit, grid)
```

I get a warning message:

> 'newdata' had 1681 rows but variables found have 100 rows

I also don't get the desired labels predicted. I don't understand what R is doing here, can somebody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning goes away if the variable names in the test data match those in the training data:

```
x1 <- c(runif(100, 0.0, 10.0))
y1 <- c(runif(100, 0.0, 10.0))

data <- data.frame(x1, y1)
data$label <- with(data, ifelse((x1-5)^2 + (y1-5)^2 < 9, 1, 0))

lm_fit <- lm(formula = label ~ .,data = data)

x_vals <- seq(0, 10, 0.25)
y_vals <- seq(0, 10, 0.25)

grid <- expand.grid(x_vals, y_vals)

colnames(grid) <- c('x1', 'y1')

predict(lm_fit, grid)
```